# Getting items for all languages using Advanced System Reporter

Tags: module

I am using [ASR](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/A/Advanced_System_Reporter.aspx) to create a report, of all items created before a certain date.

However, in my result set, I am only getting items from the current language, English, but I would like one entry for each language, like we get when we use the search in the content editor.

Is there a way to get this?

I can see, that ASR uses sitecore queries, and that the scanner in use, ItemScanner, is using the following query:

`Query=./descendant-or-self::*|Root={Root}`

However, I have not been able to edit it, so it returns entries for all language versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By digging in the [sourcecode](https://github.com/Sitecore/AdvancedSystemReporter/blob/master/Reports/Scanners/QueryScanner.cs#L52) I found out, that there is a parameter called "ShowEachLanguage" which you can use like this:

`Query=./descendant-or-self::*|Root={Root}|ShowEachLanguage=1`